# Finding outliers for all specific subsets in R?

Tags: r, loops, filter, outliers

I have several conditions and several types of measurements in my data. 
   I want R to   give me the value of the outlier for each pair of condition and type of measurement separately. 
So, for example, let's say I have 3 conditions (1-3) and 3 types of measures (A-C) for several participants, with a value x for every row. I want to have the outlier of the values x for condition1&measureA, condition2&measureB etc. 
(measure and condition are both non-numerical)

I've tried creating a loop

```
for(d in unique(data$measure)){
  for(c in unique(data$condition)){
    data %>%
      filter(measure == d, condition ==c) %>%
      o <- outlier(data$value) %>%
      print(o)
  }
}
```

The idea is that R will run through each condition and measure in a loop, and each time pick out the values that match those and calculate the outliers.
When I run the whole code I get this error message

```
Error in print.default(., o) : invalid printing digits -2147483648
In addition: Warning message:
In print.default(., o) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

(If I run it without the loop e.g. by searching for outliers for a specific condition, it also cannot find the pipe function after the first line.)

Any idea on how to code this correctly?

Comment: If you're already using `dplyr`, are you intentionally avoiding its built-in (and more efficient) `group_by` functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already using `dplyr`, so I suggest you use `group_by`, as it (to me) is a more natural way of dealing with the data.

Also, this part is incorrect syntax:

```r
    data %>%
      filter(measure == d, condition ==c) %>%
      o <- outlier(data$value) %>%
      print(o)
```

Why?

1. The `filter(...) %>%` should be piping to *something* that accepts a frame, but ... you're sending the output from `filter` into an *assignment* `o <- outlier(...)` (and then to `print(o)`, which really means `print(., o)` where `.` is the output from the previous command.
2. Further, since `o` is not yet defined the first time this runs ... you should get an error about `object 'o' not found`. You won't get it on subsequent passes in the loop, since it does exist ... but if so then it's the outliers from the *previous* iteration in the loops. Certainly not what you should be using.

A direct correction of that code might be:

```r
for (...) {
  for (...) {
    o <- data %>%
      filter(measure == d, condition ==c) %>%
      do({ data.frame(outliers = outlier(.$value)) })
    print(o)
  }
}
```

where `o` will be a `data.frame` (well, `tbl_df` tibble) with three columns: `measure`, `condition`, and `outliers`. The use of `do` is *required* in this case because most non-tidyverse functions ignore `group_by` groupings, so we use `do` to side-step that problem.

Perhaps this, though, to replace both loops into a single command:

```r
data %>%
  group_by(measure, condition) %>%
  summarize(outliers = outlier(value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I'm assuming that what you want is all outlier values for each unique combination of `measure` and `condition`, and that the `outlier(.)` function returns a vector (of some length >= 1). If no outliers are found, the `measure`/`condition` pair will not be included ... if this is a factor, then use something like

```r
data %>%
  group_by(measure, condition) %>%
  summarize(outliers = list(outlier(value))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(outliers, keep_empty = TRUE) %>%
  ungroup()
```